# Creating events where the app where the creator is the APP itself? possible?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an app using PHP that part of what its supposed to do, is:

upon a user, using it it will
a) create an event
b) be its admin
c) the user will attend that event

Is it possible for an app to be the admin? or i must use a user?

i thought of a creative idea of doing it if it's not possible for an app to be the admin
that is via a system user that will do that

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.create/

> Creates an event on behalf of the user if the application has an
>   active session key for that user; **otherwise it creates an event on
>   behalf of the application**. Applications can create events for a user
>   if the user grants the application the create_event extended
>   permission.

So you should simply create the event without an active session key for that user I guess